# Geometriclength and effective length

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

> Why is effective length of a bar magnet shorter than its geometric
>   length?
>   Blockquote

in a textbook, author wrote that, effective length is equal to  0.85 times geometric length. But didn't mention the mathematics behind it. I don't understand which keyfactor can determine the differences between geometric length and effective elgth?

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, the effective length is the distance between the poles of a magnet. It is obvious that the poles are not found at the extremities of the magnet. Thus, the effective length $l_{eff}$ is shorter than the geometric length. Now I hope that I remember this part right (didn't have time to double check in books), but the effective length is defined as

$$l_{eff}=\frac{1}{B_{0}}\int\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}$$

where $B_{0}$ is the maximum field.

Comment: can you explian the reason more explicily that `why the effective length leff is shorter than the geometric length.?`

Comment: Let's say that a bar magnet has the field lines as in this picture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Magnet0873.png . Already from this picture you can see that all the field lines converge to two point that are not located at the extremities. So the distance between the convergence points of the field lines is smaller than the length of the whole magnet. Also, I guess that if you put a test particle in the magnetic field, the path it takes should minimize the action. And the paths that the field lines trace are  related to the effective length. I'll have to think about it some more.